# Find all integer solutions.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all integer solutions for the equation $$x^2+7=2^n$$ where $n$ is a positive integer.
Now as we can see that whenever $x$ is a solution of the equation $-x$ is also the solutions of the equation so we can assume that $x\geq 0$ Now writing the equation as $$x^2=2^n-2^3+1$$ and as $x$ is odd So we can write $x=2^mt+1$ such that $t$ is a positive integer and gcd$(t, 2)=1$ So for $n\geq 5$ our equation becomes $$2^{2m}t^2+2^{m+1}t+1=2^n-2^3+1$$ $$=>2^{m+1}t(2^{m-1}t+1)=2^3(2^{n-3}+1)$$ Now as gcd$(t, 2)=1$ So we get $m+1=3=>m=2$ and $$2^{n-3}-1=2^{m-1}t^2+t$$ $$=>2^{n-3}-1=2t^2+t$$ $$=>2^{n-3}-2t^2=t+1$$ $$=>2(2^{n-4}-t^2)=t+1$$ So we get $$2(2^{\frac{n-4}{2}}+t)(2^{\frac{n-4}{2}}-t)=t+1$$ Now $$t+2^{\frac{n-4}{2}}\geq t+1$$ So we get $2^{\frac{n-4}{2}}=1$ $=>n=4$ which is not possible as $n\geq 5$ So the given equation has no integer solutions for $n\geq 5$ Also $n=1, 2, $ does not give a solution But $n=3$ gives $x=-1$ and $x=1$ as the solution and $n=5$ gives $x=-5$ and $x=5$ as the solutions of the given equation
Is this correct?

Comment: $n=15$ is a solution hence you must have made a mistake. I'm wondering how'd you get to $t+2^{(n-4)/2}\geq t+1$? As a side note you can use \implies to create the $\implies$ arrow instead of using $=>$

Comment: You get $m+1=3$ from $2^{m+1}t(2^{m-1}t+1)=2^3(2^{n-3}\color{red}{-}1)$, but I think that you also have to consider the case where $m=1$ for which $2^{m-1}t+1$ is even.